# How to stop the deduction in "wp_term_taxonomy" count, when the post is deleted?

Tags: filters, terms, count

In wordpress, the normal behavior is, when you delete a post, the system automatically performs a deduction of a post (-1) in `wp_term_taxonomy` table in `count` field from a taxonomy row which it belongs to.

**FINAL RESULT**:

- Basically, I am looking to stop this behavior, where it could not perform the deduction when a post is deleted so I could build up the statistics. What I am looking for is a function which I could use to stop this behavior. Probably with the help of filter/hook at the end when the post is deleted.

Comment: By default WordPress doesn't have ads, what plugin are you using?

Comment: Please read [ask] to see what is on topic and what isn't. And especially: Read how to ask a _really good_ question - instead of a task description.

Answer (score 1):

In short: WordPress uses the term count in various places. There's even another count that it's in the options table. So as long as you are talking about the core behavior, then the recommendation is:

> Never ever touch the WordPress cores term counting mechanism!

It's hard enough to bring it to work in some cases (manually updating term stuff in very, very custom scenarios for e.g.).

If your problem is that it is used somewhere in the public (like user admin pages or theme templates), then simply add your own counter in parallel or remove the displaying function at all.